# Sometimes when I start my pc, my keyboard doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, logitech-keyboard

I use Windows 8, and I have a Logitech G710+ keyboard.

Sometimes (about 1/10) my keyboard lights don't go on and the keyboard doesn't work after I just started my computer. In this case I usually restart using the mouse and it works.

What can be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Is it connected direct to the PC or via a USB hub?

Comment: directly. it has 2 usb cables, one for extending a usb, one for the keyboard itself

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that the keyboard has a USB port that allows another device to be plugged in via the keyboard? If so, is anything plugged in to that?

Comment: yes it has that port. and nothing is plugged in to it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I get the exact same issue with this keyboard AND my G700s mouse, the only thing that fixes it for now is to re-boot BUT I am trying something else now; in Device Manager under Human Interface Devices are MANY USB devices.  I went through all of Power Management Tabs and un-ticked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".  There are many locations with Mice and Keyboard devices and I went through all of the Power Management tabs where found.

Now I just wait and see if this worked.

If this does not work then this keyboard and mouse are going to die horribly.  I NEVER had this issue with any other KB/Mouse.

Comment: Super User is not a forum, its purpose is to build a knowledgebase.  Answers are intended to be definitive solutions.  In this format, your post is premature.  The time to post an answer would be after you have determined that it works.  This information doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to superuser! Yes, please make sure that it works and edit your answer accordingly.